# Firebase auth React dom router navigate if there is no error

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I have a sign up function that will register a user in firebase auth. My issue is that the users gets navigated to the home page even if there is a error with sign up. How can I fix my function to programmatically navigate users if there is no error durning sign up

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    try {
      //signup is a prop function
      signup(data.get("email"), data.get("password"));
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
      return;
    }

    navigate("/" + location.search);
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without additional context, I'm taking a confident guess that its most likely because your `signup` is an `async` function. Without `await` on `signup`, the `signup` will start only after `handleSubmit` finishes. In order to `await` on it, you have to declare `handleSubmit` to be an `async` arrow function.

Pay attention to the `async` and `await` I've added.

```js
const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

  try {
    await signup(data.get("email"), data.get("password"));
  } catch (error) {
    setError(error.message);
    return;
  }

  navigate("/" + location.search);
};
```

To better understand this concept, make sure you read more about [Async Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and the [JS Event Loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)